# Disable delete functionality on Webform submissions

Tags: 7, webforms, forms

I need to disable/hide the delete functionality of weform submissions.

Marked as yellow on the images below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Webform provides the following permissions, which can be controlled via the standard page at /admin/people/permissions:

- Delete all webform submissions

  > Allows deleting of any webform submission by any user. Generally an administrative permission.
- Delete own webform submissions

Once you have those set for the required roles, the delete tab will no longer appear for those users.